# Recursive push_back doesn't work on custom class

Tags: c++, class, object, gcc, vector

*I'm sure it has been asked 100 times, but `push_back` is such a popular question that I couldn't find an answer after searching for a long time.*

My problem is that on [this page](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialC++STL.html) it says that that a recursive `push_back` should work perfectly without any problem on multiple levels.

```
vector< vector<int> > vI2Matrix;    // Declare two dimensional array
vector<int> A, B;

A.push_back(10);
A.push_back(20);
A.push_back(30);
B.push_back(100);
B.push_back(200);
B.push_back(300);

vI2Matrix.push_back(A);
vI2Matrix.push_back(B);
```

However in my version I am trying to use a custom class `Vector3f` instead of `int`. I would naturally think that the following code would work, but it doesn't. It works on the 1st level, but not on the 2nd.

```
vector< vector<Vector3f> > m;
vector<Vector3f> a;
a.push_back(Vector3f(1,2,3)); // <- 1st level works
m.push_back(a); // <- 2nd level doesn't
```

The error code returned is:

```
gobase.h:343: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘* __result = * __first’
demo1.h:38: note: candidates are: Vector3f& Vector3f::operator=(Vector3f&)
```

The `Vector3f` class is defined in an external header file, what I am not supposed to modify. Do you think there is something missing from the given header file what makes me unable to use `push_back`?

The following functions are defined in the header file:

```
class Vector3f {
    float _item[3];

public:
    float & operator [] (int i) 
    Vector3f(float x, float y, float z) 
    Vector3f()
    Vector3f & operator = (Vector3f & obj) 
    Vector3f & operator += (Vector3f & obj) 
    bool operator ==(Vector3f & obj)
}
```

**Update**
Here is the `& operator =` from the header file:

```
Vector3f & operator = (Vector3f & obj) 
{
    _item[0] = obj[0];
    _item[1] = obj[1];
    _item[2] = obj[2];

    return *this;
};
```

Can you tell me how should I modify this to make `push_back` work?

**Have a look at the complete steps required to solve this problem in GCC, I posted it as an additional answer.**

Comment: You are sure about the `Vector3f` definition? All member functions are declared private.

Comment: You need to add "const" to the declaration, as follows: Vector3f& operator = (const Vector3f& obj)

Comment: @pmr, I inserted the missing lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment operator is missing from your Vector3f class. Template expansion of vector's push_back needs an assignment operator to copy the value into the vector, so the compiler complains that it cannot find it. If you get to modify that header, you will also need to define a `Vector3f(cont Vector3f& other)` copy constructor.

Comment: and the operator= should take it's input as const:  `operator= (const Vector3f& obj)`

Comment: Unless there is a good reason for the assignment operator to take a non-const reference. Which is probably not the case.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Based on these answers and on my other question here:

[How to modify a given class to use const operators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8283004/518169)

The solution required to change 3 things:

1. create the copy constructor
2. overload the [] operator with const
3. change the = operator to const

In VS2010 none of these things were needed the code compiled as it is. The change was required only in GCC.